# django custom save organization

Tags: python, django, save, models

so I am looking at a custom `save` method, and it looks something like this:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    is_created = False
    if not self.pk:
        is_created = True
    super(self, ModelName).save(*args, **kwargs)
    if is_created:
        #do something
    return True
```

I have two main questions...first...is `return True` necessary? and if so, why?...second...what is the purpose of `is_created`? why can't I just put `#do something` inside the `if not self.pk`?

## question in code:

why can't I do the following:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.pk:
        #do something
    super(self, ModelName).save(*args, **kwargs)
    return True
```

or if I can, why did the people who wrote this code do it the other way? is there a difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`save` doesn't have to return anything so you could drop the `return` statement.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.pk:
        #do something
    super(self, ModelName).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

There really isn't that much difference, unless you have to do something after the object is saved for the first time.  Once the save method is called the `pk` property should be populated, so if you need to do something to it after it is saved the first time, you need to keep track of that (as the first code sample you posted does)

---

An alternative to the first code sample could be to use [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/):

```
def do_something_only_newly_created_objects(sender, **kwargs):
   if kwargs['created']:
      # do_something()

post_save.connect(do_something_only_newly_created_objects, sender=YourModel)
```

Comment: ahhhh, so since the `#do something` was manipulating some of the fields, the object needed to be saved first! But if it was something disconnected to the actual model, it would make no difference!